# a onclick event opens box and on box submit it links to php function which set some values to db

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to create sort of alert box with an `onClick` event. The basic idea here is to create box which asks the user to select some value (checkbox) and then submit. After user clicks box submit-button it should send form values to db.

I think I won't be able to link php-function directly in an `onClick` event.

Any tips to start to creating this functionality?

Comment: A little confusing detail, maybe some codes might give more information as to what you are looking for

Comment: read ajax documentation on the web, search ajax + php + jquery maybe

Answer (score 0):

you have to use javascript and ajax methods .. you cant call php functions in you html like the on submit ... you can call javascript function and that function will call ajax request to call a php function ....

html is on client side , php is on the server side . you can communicate between then using javascript if you want .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function box(){

                document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
                document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
        }

</script>

<style>
        .black_overlay{
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0%;
            left: 0%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            z-index:1001;
            -moz-opacity: 0.8;
            opacity:.80;
            filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        }
        .white_content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 25%;
            left: 30%;
            width: 30%;
            height: 19%;
            padding: 8px;
            border: 8px solid #a31d21;
            background-color: white;
            z-index:1002;
            overflow: auto;

        }
    </style>
```

And the body...

```
<a href="#" onclick="box();">Click</a> 

<div id="light" class="white_content">

 Your form here...      

  </div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks , I tried to use that solution but there seems to be a bit of problem with it. So I have link now and when it get clicked it should pop up that form screen. Unfortunately it shows up and dissapear right after.. it might have something do do with javascript code what  i'm using to hide/show divs